# How to implement tcp-poll function in lwip stack

Tags: c, tcp, xilinx, lwip

I am programming the fpga board `ZYNQ XC7Z010-1CLG400C`. I am measuring data continuously  from an ADC, saving the data in the buffer (`MesStrBuf`) then send this buffer over ethernet using lwip satck.
when i implement the program without the function `tcp_poll()`, data transmission over ethernet is aborted. The reason that the connection over ethernet is aborted that the buffer tcp_snd_buf is getting full and the data is partly sent using tcp_write and tcp_output although i send the whole size of tcp_send_buf using the buffer (`MesStrBuf`) in every `tcp_write()`.

This is why I want to use the function `tcp_poll()` until the data is fully sent (I want to wait until the data is sent) then can I run the program continuously and repeat the program again and again without problems as I am thinking.

So i want to implement the command

```
 tcp_poll(tpcb,poll_function,1);
```

but how shall the function `poll_function()` be implemented?

is the PCB (protocol control block) of the TCP connection that i must implement in `poll_function()` is also the used `PCB(tpcb)` in `tcp_write()`?

How shall i call `tcp_write()` in `poll_function()`? or there is no need to call `tcp_write()` in the `poll_function()`?

this is the code:

```
err_t recv_callback(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *tpcb, struct pbuf *p, err_t err)
{
    for(j=0;j<count;j++)
    {
        // write buffer **MesStrBuf** for sending
        err = tcp_write(tpcb, MesStrBuf, sizeof(MesStrBuf), 1); 
        // prompt the system to send data now
        tcp_output(tpcb);
        tcp_poll(tpcb,poll_function,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_0_x/tcp_8h.html#a66deb97618a9cd9d57fca28c5245e073):

```
typedef err_t(* tcp_poll_fn) (void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *tpcb)
```